# Popen([...], stderr=PIPE) ignores input() message from spawned python program

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess, stdout, popen

I have one file running the other through the Popen().

```
# a.py
import subprocess

p = subprocess.Popen(['python3','/home/scotty/b.py'], 
stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
p.wait()

# b.py
input('???')
```

When I run a.py "???" doesn't appear but the prompt still works... why? And how can I fix it?

If I remove stderr=subprocess.PIPE then "???" does show up.

According to the docs the output of input "is written to standard output" and I'm not touching standard output.

Comment: After the `Popen`, you should call `p.communicate()`. See [this page](https://pymotw.com/3/subprocess/) that covers pretty much every basic use case of the subprocess module.

Comment: @gribouillis Honestly the reason I'm not using communicate() is because I want to be able to capture the stderr even if ctrl-c is pressed. With communicate I can't receive its return value after a keyboard interrupt. (I'm not using wait() either, that's just there for the example)

Comment: If you don't use `communicate()` nor `wait()`, how does your program wait for p's completion? I'd like an mvce...

Comment: @gribouillis I'm trying to use select.select and rad directly from p.stderr

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that in your exemple, everything happens as if opening a pipe for stderr but not for stdout has the effect of redirecting stdout to stderr because in the tests that I made, stderr receives the input's prompt.

Below is a code that works for me in linux. It is probably overcomplicated because I use socketpairs, which is most certainly not necessary, but at least it is robust and it works.

```
##################################
# a.py

import subprocess
import socket
import select

esock, echildsock = socket.socketpair()
osock, ochildsock = socket.socketpair()
p = subprocess.Popen(['python3','b.py'], 
    stderr=echildsock.fileno(),
    stdout=ochildsock.fileno())

while p.poll() is None:
    r, w, x = select.select([esock, osock],[],[], 1.0)
    if not r:
        continue # timed out
    for s in r:
        print('stdout ready' if s is osock else 'stderr ready')
        data = s.recv(1024)
        print('received', data.decode('utf8'))
osock.shutdown(socket.SHUT_RDWR)
osock.close()
esock.shutdown(socket.SHUT_RDWR)
esock.close()

##################################
# b.py

res = input('???')
print('in b:', res)
```

Comment: I'm not convinced that there's any redirection going on. Sending prompts to stderr is completely normal practice -- shell prompts go there, for instance; prompts, by definition, are status information for users, not output content.

Comment: But python's input prompt goes to stdout. It is in the doc and it can be tested easily. But in this case stderr actually receives the prompt. We could perhaps do more tests by printing some output.

Comment: I was clearly reading different docs -- the ones I looked at before commenting didn't specify stdout *or* stderr. Looking at the source, though, behavior branches on whether we have a TTY (and thus whether the prompt is actually performed by libreadline).

Comment: Huh, I'm not fully sure whats different, but it worked for me, thanks a ton!!